# how can i scale or translate a 3d element to fit scene width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am having a 3d cuboid of dimensions `100vmin` by `10vmin` by `100vmin`. The cuboid faces are housed in a parent element having a class `.board`. The scene has a perspective of `100vmax`. I have centered the cuboid in the center using the `flex` display. here is the CSS code.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
} 
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
.scene {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #888;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 100vmax;
    -moz-perspective: 100vmax;
    perspective: 100vmax;
    perspective-origin: center;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} 
.board {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    transform: rotateX(30deg);
} 
.f {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
} 
.f.ff, .f.fB {
    height: 100vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
    border: 10px solid #FFBC00;
    background: transparent;
} 
.f.fr, .f.fl {
    height: 100vmin;
    width: calc(0.1 * 100vmin);
    background: transparent;
} 
.f.ft, .f.fb {
    height: calc(0.1 * 100vmin);
    width: 100vmin;
    border: none;
    background: #9B6F00;
} 

.f.ff {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * calc(0.1 * 100vmin) ));
} 
.f.fB {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * calc(0.1 * 100vmin) ));
} 
.f.fr {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * 100vmin) );
} 
.f.fl {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * 100vmin));
} 
.f.fb {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * 100vmin));
} 
.f.ft {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(calc(.5 * 100vmin));
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
    <div class="board">
        <div class='f ff'>F</div>
        <div class='f fB'>B</div>
        <div class='f fr'>R</div>
        <div class='f fl'>L</div>
        <div class='f fb'>b</div>
        <div class='f ft'>T</div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

When I rotate the cuboid in its x-axis through say `45deg`, its absolute height will obviously change because of the perspective, hence there will be some space on its top. I wanted to remove this space and make sure it fits perfectly based on the device width.

I have tried using Javascript to get the top using this formula based on the concept of a circle and a tangent then i scale the element using the scale factor I get.

```
let height = window.innerHeight;
let front_top = (height/2) * (1-Math.sin(45 * Math.PI/180));
let bottom_top = (.1*height/2) * (1-Math.sin(45 * Math.PI/180);
let scale_factor = height/(height - front_top - bottom_top);
let average_top = (front_top + bottom_top) / 2;
```

the formula seems to be working fine but there is pixels difference due to perspective.
Kindly i need help to fit the element. Thank you in advance.